# heroku "undefined method" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

My app has an user model include a "newbie" boolean attribute. I make a radio button in signup page to let a new user choose whether he's a "newbie" or not.

```
<%= f.radio_button :newbie, true %> <%= f.label :newbie, "I'm a newbie" %>   
<%= f.radio_button :newbie, false%> <%= f.label :newbie, "I'm not a newbie" %>
```

The app runs good in local server. But after deploy to heroku, I cannot visit signup page. heroku logs show:

```
2012-04-29T20:16:16+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/signup" for 72.181.169.183 at 2012-04-29 20:16:16 +0000
2012-04-29T20:16:16+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by UsersController#new as HTML
2012-04-29T20:16:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered shared/_error_messages.html.erb (0.0ms)
2012-04-29T20:16:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered users/new.html.erb within layouts/application    (1.3ms)
2012-04-29T20:16:16+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms
2012-04-29T20:16:16+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-04-29T20:16:16+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `newbie' for #<User:0x00000004d21280>):
2012-04-29T20:16:16+00:00 app[web.1]:     6:     <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
2012-04-29T20:16:16+00:00 app[web.1]:     7:      <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
2012-04-29T20:16:16+00:00 app[web.1]:     8:    
2012-04-29T20:16:16+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:     <%= f.radio_button :newbie, false%> <%= f.label :newbie, "I'm not a newbie" %>
2012-04-29T20:16:16+00:00 app[web.1]:     9:      <%= f.radio_button :newbie, true %> <%= f.label  :newbie, "I'm a newbie" %>
2012-04-29T20:16:16+00:00 app[web.1]:     11: 
2012-04-29T20:16:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/users/new.html.erb:9:in `block in _app_views_users_new_html_erb___587113142513507349_39337120'
2012-04-29T20:16:16+00:00 app[web.1]:     12:       <%= f.label :name %>
2012-04-29T20:16:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/users/new.html.erb:6:in     `_app_views_users_new_html_erb___587113142513507349_39337120'
```

I have run the migrations and I can see newbie is successfully migrated

```
Migrating to AddRoleToUsers (20120425182820) 
==  AddRoleToUsers: migrating =================================================
-- add_column(:users, :newbie, :boolean)
 -> 0.0023s
==  AddRoleToUsers: migrated (0.0024s) ========================================
```

What could be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: I did run the migrations

Comment: Did you restart your app after running the migrations?

Comment: Which environment are you using on heroku? Which database? Are you using a procfile? Just want to be sure I know your situation before answering.

Comment: Interesting...I went to play basketball for 2 hours, then I came back home and try again, everything works like charm...Don't know exactly what happened but glad it works now!

Comment: I could be wrong but I think it may take some time for changes to take immediate effect if you check right away. Not sure but I've had similar issues before